# Creating max_value table depending on column values

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to calculate a new value using different tables but first I needed to create an auxiliary table with the limits of this calculation in order to achieve more modularity and being able to modify the limits whenever I need.

I wanted a table like this:

```
product_type      product_area    max_limit
product-100_sp         71            67.5
product-100_sp         70            22.5
product-200_se         71             80
product-200_se         70             16
```

I was trying to run this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW aux_limits AS
 SELECT DISTINCT
 mtd.product_type,
 v.product_area,
 CASE WHEN (v.product_area=70 AND mtd.product_type LIKE '%product-100%' THEN 22.5 ELSE NULL END) AS Max_Limit
 CASE WHEN (v.product_area=71 AND mtd.product_type LIKE '%product-100%' THEN 67.5 ELSE NULL END) AS Max_Limit
 CASE WHEN (v.product_area=70 AND mtd.product_type LIKE '%product-200%' THEN 16 ELSE NULL END) AS Max_Limit
 CASE WHEN (v.product_area=71 AND mtd.product_type LIKE '%product-200%' THEN 80 ELSE NULL END) AS Max_Limit
 CASE WHEN (v.product_area=70 AND mtd.product_type LIKE '%product-300%' THEN 40 ELSE NULL END) AS Max_Limit
 CASE WHEN (v.product_area=71 AND mtd.product_type LIKE '%product-300%' THEN 70 ELSE NULL END) AS Max_Limit
 CASE WHEN (v.product_area=70 AND mtd.product_type LIKE '%product-400%' THEN 40 ELSE NULL END) AS Max_Limit
 CASE WHEN (v.product_area=71 AND mtd.product_type LIKE '%product-400%' THEN 340 ELSE NULL END) AS Max_Limit
 CASE WHEN (v.product_area=70 AND mtd.product_type LIKE '%product-500%' THEN 25 ELSE NULL END) AS Max_Limit
 CASE WHEN (v.product_area=71 AND mtd.product_type LIKE '%product-500%' THEN 40 ELSE NULL END) AS Max_Limit
FROM table1 AS v, table2 AS mtd
WHERE (product_area=71 OR product_area=70)
GROUP BY 1,2
```

The structure of mtd is:

```
local_id global_id product_name    project_name      product_type
  745      896      example1         example1        product-100_test
```

And the structure of v is

```
product_key product_area      timestamp             database_id     value 
   8552          71      2016-01-01 00:00:00             3          45325
   8550          105      2016-01-01 00:00:00            3          68
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
SQL Error [500310] [42601]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "THEN" 
Position: 211;
  [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "THEN" 
Position: 211;
  [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "THEN" 
Position: 211;
```

Honestly I am total newbie on SQL so I assume that I am doing something wrong however I do not know what it is

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Although they share the same roots they are sufficiently different that you should only add the tag for the product you are using.

Comment: Remove parentheses, `CASE WHEN v.product_area=70 AND mtd.product_type LIKE '%product-200%' THEN 16 ELSE NULL END AS Max_Limit` etc

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. No aggregate functions?

Comment: GROUP BY combined with SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name edited

Comment: @jarlh Hi, even if I quit GROUP BY and I quit the parentheses does not work

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Take baby steps, as you're new to SQL. Start with a basic select columns from table. Do a JOIN to include another table. Do the GROUP BY. Add aggregate function. Include one case expression. Add another case. Etc.